# error using confusionMatrix `data` and `reference` should be factors with the same levels

Tags: r, confusion-matrix

I am using R (in R studio) for the first time so apologies for any silly mistakes.

I am running a machine learning model. In my script I get the error below,

```
Error: `data` and `reference` should be factors with the same levels. 
4. stop("`data` and `reference` should be factors with the same levels.", call. = FALSE) 
3. confusionMatrix.default(Y.pr, Y.ob)
```

When I step into the confusionMatrix I'm a little confused.

The data (my Y.pr) variable is stored under the Data section whilst reference (my Y.ob) is stored under values. When I click on reference it shows

```
num [1:8593] 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 ...
```

my data variable when I expand it looks like below.

```
Large matrix (8593 elements, 604.6 kb)
- attr(*, "dimnames")= List of 2
..$ : chr [1:8593] "34371" "34372" "34373" "34374" ...
..$ : NULL
```

None of which makes any sense to me. I'm guessing the Null is causing the problem?

**update**

Using the same data I am able to run a fully working model in Python

**end of update**

Comment: The error suggests you need both variables as factor with the same number of levels. from what I can see, you have classes `num` and `chr`. My suggestion is you provide a minimal reproducible example for us to work on.

Comment: Have you checked that the levels the same -- are your values zero or one?
Have you tried setting `Y.ob` and `Y.pr` to a `factor` as one of them (not sure which) is numeric. For example, wit h this example data `Y.pr = sample(0:1, 10, TRUE); Y.ob = sample(0:1, 10, TRUE)` we get the same error by using `caret::confusionMatrix(Y.pr, Y.ob)`. After setting to a factor
we do not `caret::confusionMatrix(factor(Y.pr), factor(Y.ob))`

Comment: ps it may be useful to add the results of `dput(Y.pr[1:10])` and `dput(Y.obs[1:10])` to your question please. Also is `confusionMatrix` from `caret` or ??

Answer (score 2):

I'll work off of the example from `?confusionMatrix` to get to your error and then one way to recover from it.

## Up Front

The way this answer steps through fixing things is by assigning levels to a non-`factor` variable. If you do not *know with certainty* what the numeric levels indicate relative to `pred`, then your clinical study is over: any results are suspect and indefensible. The rest of the answer assumes that you are certain about the levels (or that you are just playing anyway, and there is not formal study or survey or whatever with this data). Even if the original data did not come as `factor`s, verifying what a "1" and what a "2" (or whatever the number are) means is the critical step.

## Demonstration

```r
library(caret)
lvs <- c("normal", "abnormal")
truth <- factor(rep(lvs, times = c(86, 258)),
                levels = rev(lvs))
pred <- factor(
  c(
    rep(lvs, times = c(54, 32)),
    rep(lvs, times = c(27, 231))),
  levels = rev(lvs))

head(truth)
# [1] normal normal normal normal normal normal
# Levels: abnormal normal
head(pred)
# [1] normal normal normal normal normal normal
# Levels: abnormal normal
```

Normal (ideal) execution:

```r
confusionMatrix(pred, truth)
# Confusion Matrix and Statistics
#           Reference
# Prediction abnormal normal
#   abnormal      231     32
#   normal         27     54
#                                           
#                Accuracy : 0.8285          
#                  95% CI : (0.7844, 0.8668)
#     No Information Rate : 0.75            
#     P-Value [Acc > NIR] : 0.0003097       
#                                           
#                   Kappa : 0.5336          
#  Mcnemar's Test P-Value : 0.6025370       
#                                           
#             Sensitivity : 0.8953          
#             Specificity : 0.6279          
#          Pos Pred Value : 0.8783          
#          Neg Pred Value : 0.6667          
#              Prevalence : 0.7500          
#          Detection Rate : 0.6715          
#    Detection Prevalence : 0.7645          
#       Balanced Accuracy : 0.7616          
#                                           
#        'Positive' Class : abnormal
```

But what if the second argument is not a factor?

```r
truth_num <- as.integer(truth)
head(truth_num)
# [1] 2 2 2 2 2 2
confusionMatrix(pred, truth_num)
# Error: `data` and `reference` should be factors with the same levels.
```

## The Fix

What we need to do is bring `truth_num` back to a factor.

First, the theory: if it was at one point a `factor` and somehow converted to `integer`, then it is a bunch of 1s and 2s (originally, the indices on its levels). If it never was a factor, it could be any numbers, really, but the bottom line is this: do we know which (integer) is which (level)? If you guess incorrectly, then your test will give absolutely wrong results (with no error/warning).

```r
table(pred)
# pred
# abnormal   normal 
#      263       81 
table(truth_num)
# truth_num
#   1   2 
# 258  86
```

Just looking at the relative proportions *suggests* that the levels for `truth_num` should be the same, as in `c("abnormal", "normal")`. (But please read my top note again about chasing-results; don't trust proportions, go back to the source data to find out which is which.) This is how we set that up. There are several ways to go from indices to factors, here are two:

```r
### one way
truth_num_fac <- factor(truth_num)
levels(truth_num_fac)
# [1] "1" "2"
head(truth_num_fac)
# [1] 2 2 2 2 2 2
# Levels: 1 2
levels(truth_num_fac) <- levels(pred)
head(truth_num_fac)
# [1] normal normal normal normal normal normal
# Levels: abnormal normal

### another way
dput(head(pred))
# structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("abnormal", "normal"
# ), class = "factor")
truth_num_fac <- structure(truth_num, .Label = levels(pred), class = "factor")
head(truth_num_fac)
# [1] normal normal normal normal normal normal
# Levels: abnormal normal
```

Either way, the test now works.

```r
confusionMatrix(pred, truth_num_fac)
# Confusion Matrix and Statistics
#           Reference
# Prediction abnormal normal
#   abnormal      231     32
#   normal         27     54
#                                           
#                Accuracy : 0.8285          
#                  95% CI : (0.7844, 0.8668)
#     No Information Rate : 0.75            
#     P-Value [Acc > NIR] : 0.0003097       
#                                           
#                   Kappa : 0.5336          
#  Mcnemar's Test P-Value : 0.6025370       
#                                           
#             Sensitivity : 0.8953          
#             Specificity : 0.6279          
#          Pos Pred Value : 0.8783          
#          Neg Pred Value : 0.6667          
#              Prevalence : 0.7500          
#          Detection Rate : 0.6715          
#    Detection Prevalence : 0.7645          
#       Balanced Accuracy : 0.7616          
#                                           
#        'Positive' Class : abnormal        
#
```

## **What If ...**

- the levels are correct, but you see this warning:

  ```r
  confusionMatrix(pred, truth_num_fac)
  # Warning in confusionMatrix.default(pred, truth_num_fac) :
  #   Levels are not in the same order for reference and data. Refactoring data to match.
  # Confusion Matrix and Statistics
  ### ...
  ```

  This indicates that your levels are not in the same order. The fix is not hard:

  ```r
  levels(pred)
  # [1] "abnormal" "normal"
  levels(truth_num_fac)
  # [1] "normal"   "abnormal"                     <---- abnormal should be first, according to pred
  truth_num_fac <- relevel(truth_num_fac, "abnormal")
  confusionMatrix(pred, truth_num_fac)
  # Confusion Matrix and Statistics
  ```
- the levels are incorrect? you will get no error or warning, though your test results will be quite different; this doesn't mean you should chase the desired results, but if they are drastically wrong, it is cause for concern:

  ```r
  ### setup for backwards data
  truth_num_fac_backwards <- structure(truth_num, .Label = rev(levels(pred)), class = "factor")
  truth_num_fac_backwards <- relevel(truth_num_fac_backwards, "abnormal")
  head(truth_num_fac_backwards)
  # [1] abnormal abnormal abnormal abnormal abnormal abnormal
  # Levels: abnormal normal

  confusionMatrix(pred, truth_num_fac_backwards)
  # Confusion Matrix and Statistics
  #           Reference
  # Prediction abnormal normal
  #   abnormal       32    231
  #   normal         54     27
  #                                           
  #                Accuracy : 0.1715              <----- OUCH
  #                  95% CI : (0.1332, 0.2156)
  #     No Information Rate : 0.75            
  #     P-Value [Acc > NIR] : 1               
  #                                           
  #                   Kappa : -0.3103         
  #  Mcnemar's Test P-Value : <2e-16          
  #                                           
  #             Sensitivity : 0.37209         
  #             Specificity : 0.10465         
  #          Pos Pred Value : 0.12167         
  #          Neg Pred Value : 0.33333         
  #              Prevalence : 0.25000         
  #          Detection Rate : 0.09302         
  #    Detection Prevalence : 0.76453         
  #       Balanced Accuracy : 0.23837         
  #                                           
  #        'Positive' Class : abnormal        
  #
  ```

  The proper way to address this is to go back and verify which level is which. It might be that you got it right, and the results tell you things are not a good match. Any other fixes would be (in my opinion) chasing the results: make sure you get the data right the first time, don't change the data to match your expected results.
- I tried to convert the number vector to a `factor`, but `levels(...)` returns `NULL`.

  This is likely because your non-numeric vector is not a `factor`, but instead `character`. This fix should be easy enough:

  ```r
  ### setup for fake character data
  pred_chr <- pred
  pred_chr <- as.character(pred)
  head(pred_chr)
  # [1] "normal" "normal" "normal" "normal" "normal" "normal"

  ### the remedy
  pred_chr_fac <- factor(pred_chr)
  head(pred_chr_fac)
  # [1] normal normal normal normal normal normal
  # Levels: abnormal normal
  levels(pred_chr_fac)
  # [1] "abnormal" "normal"
  ```